# Visual glitches with custom field editor

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

I have an `NSTextField` where I want auto-complete to always operate on the full content of the field, rather than the current word.

I'm trying to do this by using `windowWillReturnFieldEditor()` in the window delegate to return an `NSTextView` subclass, where I can return the full text range in `rangeForUserCompletion`.

This is essentially working, except for some drawing issues. The text field's focus ring does not get drawn, and the field's old text is overlaid on what is currently being typed.

Is there some additional configuring I need to do on the `NSTextView` to make it work properly as a field editor? I think an alternative would be to customize what constitutes a word boundary, but I haven't found how to do that.

The relevant code:

```swift
extension MyWindowController: NSWindowDelegate
{
  func windowWillReturnFieldEditor(_ sender: NSWindow, to client: Any?) -> Any?
  {
    if let clientField = client as? NSTextField,
       clientField === myTextField {
      let editor = FullReplacementTextView()

      editor.isFieldEditor = true
      return editor
    }
    else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}

class FullReplacementTextView: NSTextView
{
  override var rangeForUserCompletion: NSRange
  {
    return self.string.fullNSRange // Extension method that returns the full string range
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is you have to return the same instance every time, rather than creating a new one at each callback. Caching an instance and returning that solved the problem.

Now it turns out if you type a non-alphanumeric character, the auto-complete logic counts that as "I want to accept the selected completion and also type this character", even if that was the next character in the completion. But I'm going to tackle that as a separate question.